# How to get text of perticular area in scanned file from many file to save with that text to file

Tags: c#

I am making small for scanned file reader in `c#`.
client requirment is to provide facility to select area in scan file by which he can specify which have to read.
I made this using below code

```
 public string ReadCharacter(string fileName)
 {
            string value = "";
            try
            {
                Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte> img = new Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>(fileName);
                System.Drawing.Rectangle staticRec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(General.Rect_X, General.Rect_Y, General.Rect_Width, General.Rect_Height);
                //img.ROI = staticRec;
                var _ocr = new Tesseract(@"D:\", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractCubeCombined);
                _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890");
                _ocr.Recognize(img);
                General.selectedString = _ocr.GetText();
                char[] array1 = { '\n', '\r' };
                General.selectedString = General.selectedString.Trim(array1);
                img.ROI = staticRec;
                _ocr.Recognize(img);
                value = _ocr.GetText();
               // MessageBox.Show(value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Valid Area    " + ex.Message);
            }
           // MessageBox.Show(value);

            return value;
 }
```

but it not working properly with all files.

Any one can help me please.

Comment: Please put your code in a code block (select it and press Ctrl+K).

Comment: Please provide solution of my problem..

Comment: You will increase the chance of of getting a solution if you describe your problem. Terms like *"not working properly"* and *"my problem"* are way to unspecific to provide a useful answer. What is the expected vs. the actual result? You say it's not working *"with all files"*. For which files is it working? What external libraries are you using? etc.

Comment: using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;

Comment: using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;  I am using this external libraries                                                               Problem is "Read text from a scanned files that is Image"
I have thousands of file in same format.
First, I open a file in picturebox from where use/client select area on picturebox.At time of select of area I capture co-ordinate of rectangle by which I will read text from other files. and save other files with selected area text.

Comment: suppose a scan file have thousands of cheque .
I have to splite scan into multiple file and Name will be cheque number that is unique for every cheque.
first time use will specify where cheque number has been written by drawing rectangle with mouse.According reactangle or selected area read text and save with that text.

Comment: please provide solution..